# Aggregation queries on nested array of objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following collection. each document may be represented as following. there can be multiple customer referees for each document.

```
{
  _id:objectId(""),
  customerId: "Some Id",
  name: "Customer name",
  customerReferee: [
   {
     status: 'COMPLETED',
     name: "Referee name1"
   },
   {
     status: 'PENDING',
     name: "Referee name2"
   },
  ],
}
```

I would like to have top 20 documents who has maximum number of 'COMPLETED' customerReferees.

Comment: your question is not clear, *20 documents who has maximum number of 'COMPLETED'* => describe maximum means how many?

Comment: There can be any number of COMPLETED referees. I want to order documents in descending order where document which has most number of COMPLETED referees will be the first and later the document which has lesser number of referees than first one. I want first 20 of such documents. @turivishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` status condition
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `customerReferee` array nad filter by `status`
- `$size` to get total elements in above filter result
- `$sort` by total element that we have added a field `customerRefereeSize` in descending order
- `$skip` to start cursor from 0
- `$limit` to get first 20 elements

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "customerReferee.status": "COMPLETED" } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      customerRefereeSize: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$customerReferee",
            cond: { $eq: ["$$this.status", "COMPLETED"] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { customerRefereeSize: -1 } },
  { $skip: 0 },
  { $limit: 20 }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/upbd04qOle3)

Comment: Thanks @turivishal . Its working in playground but In my database its throwing '"Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'",
 "code" : 40324,' this error. What might be the cause?

Comment: i am not sure but try `$addFields` instead of `$set`, let me know it is working or not.

Comment: Thanks for update. Now the error is gone and it's working fine. ✌